# C++ Sending mail using CSmtp library

Tags: c++, email, smtp

I'm trying to send email using CSmtp
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/SMTP-Client-with-SSL-TLS

These lines of code is causing the harm here:

```
if((sockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(szServer)) == INADDR_NONE)
{
    LPHOSTENT host;

    host = gethostbyname(szServer);
    if (host)
        memcpy(&sockAddr.sin_addr,host->h_addr_list[0],host->h_length);
    else
    {
#ifdef LINUX
        close(hSocket);
#else
        closesocket(hSocket);
#endif
        throw ECSmtp(ECSmtp::WSA_GETHOSTBY_NAME_ADDR);
    }               
}
```

`inet_addr` and `gethostbyname` isn't working anymore.

```
'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings

'gethostbyname': Use getaddrinfo() or GetAddrInfoW() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings
```

How could I get this to work using `inet_pton()` and `getaddrinfo()`?
I have tried to find solution but havent found anything yet so far...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be something like that:

```
#ifdef LINUX

   int retVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, czServer,  &sockAddr.sin_addr);
#else
   int retVal = InetPton(AF_INET, czServer,  &sockAddr.sin_addr);

#endif

if(retVal != 1)
{

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    #ifdef LINUX
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    #else
        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    #endif


    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;


    getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &result);

    if (host)
        memcpy(&sockAddr.sin_addr,result->ai_addr,result->ai_addrlen);
        freeaddrinfo(result);
    else
    {
#ifdef LINUX
        close(hSocket);
#else
        closesocket(hSocket);
#endif
        throw ECSmtp(ECSmtp::WSA_GETHOSTBY_NAME_ADDR);
    }               
}
```

Based on:

Windows:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx

Linux:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo
- http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html